# React-Google-Map multiple Info window open

Tags: html, reactjs, marker, infowindow, react-google-maps

I am currently building a google map api using react-google-maps and I would like to create multiple markers to display info of cities around the world on the info window. But since they are all from the html object. Whenever I clicked on one marker, all info windows will be opened. If there a way to fix this? Sample code:

```
<GoogleMap
    defaultZoom={3}
    defaultCenter={{ lat: 40.452906, lng: 190.818206 }}
  >
    <Marker id = "mark1"
      options={{icon: Mark1}} 
      position={{ lat: 34.4076645, lng: 108.742099 }}
      onClick={props.onToggleOpen}
    >
      {props.isOpen && <InfoWindow id = "info1"
                    onCloseClick={props.onToggleOpen}
                    >
                    <div> content1 </div>
      </InfoWindow>}
    </Marker>
    <Marker
      options={{icon: Mark2}} 
      position={{ lat: 35.6958783, lng: 139.6869534 }}
      onClick={props.onToggleOpen}
    >
      {props.isOpen && <InfoWindow
                    onCloseClick={props.onToggleOpen}
                    >
                    <div> content2 </div>
      </InfoWindow>}
    </Marker>
</GoogleMap>
```

Comment: Just bind each info marker separately to the map

Comment: did you solve your issue ? can u provide us a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `onClick` of `Marker` you just call `{props.onToggleOpen}`, which i hope toggles a flag. Here you should send which marker you are clicking so you need to modify your `onClick` to something like below

```
onClick={() => { props.onToggleOpen("mark1"); }}
```

In the above line, `Mark1` should be a unique value that you can use to identify the respective `Marker`. You can replace this with the marker id or of something that will be unique to the respective `Marker`.

Second, you need to modify `onToggleOpen` to toggle the flag for the respective `marker` which is identified by the argument it receives(the unique value you send from `onClick). You can use an array like data structure to store this value.

Then you need to show your `InfoWindow` based on the flag respective to the `Marker`. Considering `isOpen` will be an array of flags(after incorporating the above changes), one would show `InfoWindow` using condition something like below

```
<Marker id = "mark1"
  options={{icon: Mark1}} 
  position={{ lat: 34.4076645, lng: 108.742099 }}
  onClick={() => { props.onToggleOpen("mark1"); }}
>
  {props.isOpen["mark1"] && <InfoWindow id = "info1"
                onCloseClick={() => { props.onToggleOpen("mark1"); }}
                >
                <div> content1 </div>
  </InfoWindow>}
</Marker>
```

Hope that leads you to a right direction.

Comment: Could you please post an example of how you solved this @user8832622 ?